# Database Parent -> Child "firstborn" relation

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a database-design problem. To illustrate my problem imagine the following:

A simple parent->child relation:

```
[Parent] 1-----* [Children]
```

Now every Parent (mum or dad) has a firstborn child when there are any children. I need a strong relation in database from Parent to the Firstborn-Child

```
[Parent] 1-----1 [Children]
```

I could simply add a FirstbornChildId to the Parent Table, but i do not like this approach since It could result in inconsistent data. (FirstbornChildId links to a Child which ParentId links to a different parent...)

Entity Framework should map the relation, so that every Parent-Entity has a FirstbornEntity property linking to the specific Child.

**Is there any nice way to achieve this in Microsoft SQL 2008 R2?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your approach is fine. You'll have to prevent data corruption in the application layer. There is only so much you can do with database constraints. You could at least have a foreign key for FirstbornChildId to make sure that the child does indeed exist (regardless of parent).

This "firstborn" attribute is denormalization anyway: it can be derived from having a "birthdate" attribute on the children. I appreciate that you want to store it explicitly for performance reasons, and there is no problem with it. But if you want to have the database handle integrity completely, this does make things tricky.

Comment: Funny...that's the same solution I posted in my comments above. Anyway, if you use the computed column idea I believe SQL Server can let you specify that the computed column be stored so that it's not computed *every* time the data is requested. That'll solve the performance issue.

Comment: Here is another, convoluted idea: Child has a column 'firstborn_parent_id'. It can be null. If not null, it must be set to the same value as 'parent_id' (this should be constrainable) and this means that the child is firstborn. And then you make a unique sparse index on 'firstborn_parent_id' (sparse, so that you can have multiple nulls).

Answer (score 2):

### Two possible solutions

Three tables:

- **Parent table**
- **Children table**
- **FirstBorns table**

  - id in parent
  - id in children

or

**Column WasFirstBorn** in Children table (Y/N or 1/0)

Comment: "but i do not like this approach since It could result in inconsistent data" How do these two approaches address this concern?

Comment: The three tables solution I find too complex to manage and with the second approach I think I cant create a foreign relation in T-SQL. (next to the problem Mahmoud is pointing out)

Comment: @thilo the only possible way I think is with triggers.

Comment: You can put a "dateBorn" field in the Children table and create a computed column "isFirstBorn" that checks dateBorn with parentId to determine which child is the firstBorn. This will ensure that only child per parent has isFirstBorn == true.

Comment: @Tundey: that would be neat. Does sql-server have such a feature? Note that it is a computed column whose value is derived from a multi-row query.

Comment: @Thilo: I know SQL has computed column and the query can only be so complicated...but it's worth checking.

Comment: Looks like SQL won't let you use aggregate functions in computed columns. However since you are using EF, just create a partial class for your Children class and add a property for "IsFirstBorn".